# Problem when I try to validate an XSD document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

When I put the restriction to my XSD document for the label "number" (numero), when I validate it I get an error. If I remove the restriction, the XSD document is validated. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alumno dni="12345678A"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="alumno.xsd">
  <nombre>Juan Garcia</nombre>
  <direccion>
    <calle>Avenida de la Fuente</calle>
    <numero>6</numero>
    <ciudad>Zafra</ciudad>
    <provincia>Badajoz</provincia>
  </direccion>
  <telefono>924555555</telefono>
  <telefono>658741236</telefono>
</alumno>

<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="alumno">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="nombre"/>
        <xs:element name="direccion">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="calle"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="numero"/>
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                    <xs:maxExclusive value="500"/>
                </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ciudad"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="provincia"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="telefono" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dni"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please include in your question the actual error message you got. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you defined the element `numero` with two types: you defined it as `xs:byte` and, at the same time, tried to create an `xs:simpleType` (which boundaries also exceed the limit of a byte). Also you didn't include the `xs:simpleType` in the `xs:element` definition.

So fix your definition of the element `numero` to

```
<xs:element name="numero">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
          <xs:maxExclusive value="500"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

and everything will work as desired.